# Chi-Square Table Function in Julia

Tags: function, julia

What is the function in Julia to get the values from the Chi Squared Table for a given level of degrees of freedom and level alpha?

I'm talking about this: http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~mga/401/tables/Chi-square-table.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the `cquantile` function in the [Distributions](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl) package:

```
using Distributions
cquantile(Chisq(11), .995) # = 2.603
```